# How to export georeferenced JPG raster from Google Earth Engine

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, google-earth-engine, export, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I want to export a georeferenced raster from Google Earth Engine in JPG (or similar image) format to import it to ArcGIS Desktop. The idea is that in ArcMap it looks as similar as possible to what is seen in the Google web map. I tried exporting GeoTIFF, but the result (first image) is not what I need (second image).

[image: Arcmap result][image: GEE layer]

**Script code:**

```
/* DATA SOURCE */
var NOAA = ee.Image('NOAA/NGDC/ETOPO1');
var ALOS = ee.Image('JAXA/ALOS/AW3D30/V2_2').multiply(4);

/* AREA */
var area = 
    ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[-72.1, -23.8],
          [-72.1, -29.1],
          [-67.5, -29.1],
          [-67.5, -23.8]]], null, false);

/* TERRAIN */
/* Traditional Hillshade (input,azimuth,altitude).multiply(weight) */
var N = ee.Terrain.hillshade(ALOS,0,36).multiply(0);
var NE = ee.Terrain.hillshade(ALOS,45,44).multiply(0);
var E = ee.Terrain.hillshade(ALOS,90,56).multiply(0);
var SE = ee.Terrain.hillshade(ALOS,135,68).multiply(0);
var S = ee.Terrain.hillshade(ALOS,180,80).multiply(0.1);
var SW = ee.Terrain.hillshade(ALOS,225,68).multiply(0.2);
var W = ee.Terrain.hillshade(ALOS,270,56).multiply(0.2);
var NW = ee.Terrain.hillshade(ALOS,315,44).multiply(0.5);

/* Multidirectional Hillshade */
var MULTI = N
            .add(NE)
              .add(E)
                .add(SE)
                  .add(S)
                    .add(SW)
                      .add(W)
                        .add(NW)
                        .visualize({
                          min:0,
                          max:255,
                          palette:['#000000','#ffffff'],
                          })
                        .resample('bicubic')
                        .updateMask(0.5);
/* Slope */
var SLOPE = ee.Terrain.slope(ALOS)
                      .multiply(2)
                      .visualize({
                        min:100,
                        max:180,
                        palette:['#ffffff','#000000']
                        })
                      .resample('bicubic')
                      .updateMask(1);
/* Shaded Relief */
var SHADED_RELIEF = ee.ImageCollection([
                      SLOPE,
                      MULTI
                      ])
                      .mosaic()
                      .reduce(ee.Reducer.median())
                      .updateMask(1)
                      .clip(area);
Map.addLayer(
  SHADED_RELIEF,{
      min:0,
      max:255,
      gamma:1
      },
    'Shaded Relief',
  true
);

/* Map Center (lon, lat, zoom) */
Map.setCenter(
               
              /* Center to area  */
                  -69.8,-26.5,7
              );
```